# JSON parsing with SwiftyJSON - Trouble updating UI

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I have written the following code which pulls data from the Dark Sky API. I am parsing it with SwiftyJSON but then I can't get my UI label 'wind' to display the wind speed.

I think the error may be in my parsing. I have used a JSON encoder to find the parameter I want to pull i.e. windSpeed but I don't know if it is this part which I have got wrong or it is in updating the UI itself. When I do the get request for the API I also get multiple instances of the request so maybe the issue is stemming from there too?

My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let base_URL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[API Key here]/"

    //Instance variable
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let windDataModel = WindDataModel()

    @IBOutlet weak var windDirectionArrow: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var yard: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var gust: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var wind: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Location manager set up
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    //Get wind data method
    func getWindData(url: String, latitude: String, longitude: String) {
        let urlStr = "\(base_URL)\(latitude),\(longitude)"
        Alamofire.request(urlStr, method: .get, parameters:nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { [weak self] response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                print("Success! Got the weather data")
                let windJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(windJSON)
                self!.updateWindData (json: windJSON)
            }  else {
                print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))") }
            self?.wind.text = "Connection issues"
        }
    }

    //MARK: - JSON Parsing
    /***************************************************************/
    //
    //    //Write the updateWeatherData method here:
    func updateWindData(json: JSON) {
        let windSpeed = json["currently"]["windSpeed"].doubleValue
        windDataModel.speed = Double(windSpeed)
        updateUIWithWindData()
    }

    ////    //Write the updateUIWithWeatherData method here:
    func updateUIWithWindData() {
        wind.text = "\(windDataModel.speed)"
        //Did update method
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
            if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
                self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                self.locationManager.delegate = nil

                let latitude = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
                let longitude = String(location.coordinate.longitude)

                getWindData(url: base_URL, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            }
        }

        //Did fail with error method
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print(error)
            wind.text = "Error"
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You do might want to give the JSON. You do this: `let windSpeed = json["currently"]["windSpeed"].doubleValue` Does at least: ` json["currently"]` returns something ? Then `json["currently"]["windSpeed"`? Could it be the `doubleValue` that is causing an issue?

Comment: When I parse the json using only [currently] I still get nothing in the UI. I tried to print the result into the debug console but I'm getting nothing there too...

Comment: firstly put a breakpoint to find out windJSON has got some value. If it has, then make sure you update UI on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some braces out of place is all.

```
func updateUIWithWindData() {

  wind.text = "\(windDataModel.speed)"
```

After this function, place the ending brace immediately following the `wind.text = "...` You have the ending brace near the bottom of the class.

Also, you have another brace out of place with this else statement:

```
else {
  print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))") }
  self?.wind.text = "Connection issues"
```

The brace at the end of the `print("Error...` line should be moved after `"Connection issues"`.

Fix those and your code should work fine.